# Unity Sprite not changing on command?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This Sprite:

[image]

Is supposed to change into one of these Sprites (depending on the one that is loaded)

[image]

When a Collider (LoseCollider) makes contact with a different game object:

[image]

My issue is that when the LoseCollider gets triggered the Spite is not changing and no errors are thrown at me.

The relevant code is:

HealthManager.cs

```
public static Sprite[] healthSprites;
public static int totalHealth = 3;

public static Sprite Health1; 
public static Sprite Health2;
public static Sprite Health3;
```

LoseCollider.cs

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D trigger) {
    if (HealthManager.totalHealth == 3) {
        setSprite();
        HealthManager.totalHealth --;
    } else {
        levelManager = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<LevelManager>();
        levelManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
    }
}

void setSprite () {
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = HealthManager.Health2;
}
```

I tried to post all relevant information, please let me know if I need to include more.

Comment: Are you sure that `setSprite` is getting called? Are you sure that `HealthManager.Health2` is indeed linked to the Health2 sprite and not Health3 or something?

Comment: setSprite is being called (I omitted the print statement in the method). From what I have read (not an expert on programming less than a year experience) this line:     
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = HealthManager.Health2;  

Should call health2. I'm not sure how I can check the linkage

Comment: What do you mean "Should call health2"?  Do you actually have your Health2 sprite associated with "public static Sprite Health2" on your HealthManager object?

Comment: I had them connected in the inspector before they were static (I tried a different method of getting this to work) but after making them static the inspector doesn't offer the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop using static for this.  It appears HealthManager.Health2 is never set to anything besides null.  If I'm interpreting your screenshots correctly you can see Sprite is None on your bottom shot.

Also, your code appears to show that you really don't want HealthManager attributes to be static.  You want real separate instance of HealthManager with independent health values based on your usage here:

```
if (HealthManager.totalHealth == 3) {
    setSprite();
    HealthManager.totalHealth --;
```

Nix all the static stuff on HealthManager, add a real instance of HealthManager to your GameObject and associates it's Health1-3 sprites with real references to your sprites and it should work.

The following syntax is correct assuming you update HealthManager as described above:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = HealthManager.Health2;
```